# Defining PHP Variables After Specific Part Of HTML (ECHO) Code

Tags: php, variables, echo

at the moment I'm having a tough time with HTML, PHP and Javascript! I'm trying to learn those three scripting languages at a time but there are some issues which I cannot solve on my own.

My problem is this: I've coded a PHP file. The code in it looks like this

```
<?php
$variable1=300;
$variable2=600;
and so on

echo'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
blabla
else{if
(blah.blah==(something)){**FUNCTION()**;}}
</body>
</html>'
?>
```

**Now** the thing is, i want to insert right into that part where **FUNCTION()** is stated, something along these lines:

```
$phpvar=20;
```

HOW can i insert there my PHP variable without getting any errors?!

would be really glad if someone could help me out,

thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

the problme is I've used the code "ECHO blahblah" so your ideas won't really help me. I've edited my source in order to use your suggestions but still i cannot figure it out...

Now my code looks like:

```
<?php
$variable1=300;
$variable2=600;
and so on
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
blah

<div id="blah" style="margin:0;padding:0;position:absolute;left:' . $variable1 . 'px;top:' . $variable2 . 'px;width:148px;height:57px;text-align:left;z-index:3;">
</body>
</html>
```

how can i insert variables to make it really work?  does not work..

Answer (score 0):

Not *quite* sure what you code is doing, but what about this?

```
<?php

$variable1 = 300;
$variable2 = 600;

$blah = 'something';

$phpvar = 'I am here';

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<?php

if ($phpvar != '') {
?>
<script>
var phpvar = "<?php echo $phpvar?>";
</script>
<?php
}

?>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello world!</p>
<?php
if ($blah == 'something'){
?>
<script>
function doStuff(){
    alert('Stuff done.');
}
</script>
<?php
}
?>
<p>After stuff</p>
<?php
if ($blah != 'something'){
?>
<script>
function noStuff();
</script>
<?php
} else {
?>
<p>No stuff done this time.</p>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

http://codepad.org/4hbVRJID

Which will output:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script>
var phpvar = "I am here";
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello world!</p>
<script>
function doStuff(){
    alert('Stuff done.');
}
</script>
<p>After stuff</p>
<p>No stuff done this time.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Note how I use the PHP tags (`<?php ?>`) to interpolate the PHP within the markup. This is often done when using PHP as a templating engine (on top of any logic done separately). This way you don't have to deal with the `echo`, but it can sometimes be hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Well my first suggestion would be to change the way you output your data to the browser i.e.

```
<?php
$variable1=300;
$variable2=600;
and so on
//instead of doing an echo and echo-ing all the stuff out you just temporarily end your code
?>
```

then you output your HTML here and your JavaScript code, and you insert a php block when you need to input it into JavaScript like this:

```
var SomeVar = <?php echo $variable1; ?>;
```

and so on...

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<?php
$variable1=300;
$variable2=600;
// and so on
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<!-- blabla, some HTML, some JavaScript, etc. -->
  if (blah.blah==(something)){
<?php
  $phpvar = 20;
  // some other PHP code
  echo $phpvar;
?>
  }
</body>
</html>
```

There are a number of different ways to accomplish this, and somebody may be able to answer with a way that's more idiomatic in PHP (it's been a while since I've done PHP).  Essentially what I'm doing here is a couple of things:

1. I've separated the PHP code from the HTML markup a little bit.  This is often preferred over large `echo` statements for readability, maybe performance, etc.  There's no need to `echo` large chunks of static HTML, just treat it as regular HTML outside of the PHP tags.  (This will make it a lot easier to develop and read as well, since you won't have to escape things or deal with PHP strings in your HTML code.)
2. I added a second PHP tag for the code that's in the middle of the page.  I imagine you'll want to do more than just assign a variable, and you can.  Anything you echo in that section of code will end up in that part of the rendered HTML output.  You can also write loops around your HTML, which would repeat it just like it was part of the PHP code, etc.

The main thing is to keep the PHP code contextually separate from the HTML/JavaScript that it emits.  The PHP code gets processed on the server before the page renders in the browser.  Once the page is delivered to the browser, the PHP code is done and effectively no longer exists.  At that point it's a plain HTML/JavaScript page being rendered and executed in the browser.  While it's not clear what you're actually trying to do in your resulting HTML/JavaScript in the question, you'll want to make sure in your final code you make it clear and easy to understand and don't try to mix JavaScript with PHP.  (At least not without understanding the separation and using it accordingly, such as with AJAX calls.)